# axon 3 separate command and query service via rabbitmq: json vs. xml

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, axon

I am working on a scenario, where command and query service are separated nodes (spring boot). 
I configured the RabbitTemplate to use Jackson for JSON serialization:

```
@Bean
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter) {
  final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new  RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
  rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(converter);
  return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
  return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}
```

This works, when I send the command to the command service, I can check the correct JSON format in the RabbitMQ queue.

My Aggregate receives the commands and triggers events, these are correctly stored in a mysql-eventstore. Here, the events are in xml format.

Now comes the tricky part. I use axon-springboot to send the events to a rabbit queue again via property:

```
axon.amqp.exchange: my-event-exchange
```

Again, this works, I can check the queue and see the event (in xml format).

On the Queue-Service, I want to receive the events and produce an in memory h2 representation ... I use:

```
@Bean
public SpringAMQPMessageSource myMessageSource(Serializer serializer, EventHandlingConfiguration ehConfig) {
   return new SpringAMQPMessageSource(serializer) {
      @RabbitListener(queues = "my-event-queue")
      @Override
      public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {
           log.info("receiving event: {}#{}", message, channel);
           super.onMessage(message, channel);
      }
    };
   }

   @Autowired
   public void configure(EventHandlingConfiguration ehConfig, SpringAMQPMessageSource myMessageSource) {
     ehConfig.registerSubscribingEventProcessor(
          "taskQueryObjectUpdater", c -> myMessageSource);
   }
```

as stated in the documentation.

But, in while I see the "receiving event" log, I get a

```
2017-06-16 15:17:38.168  WARN 69212 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.s.c.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter   : Could not convert incoming message with content-type [null]
```

warning and my h2-repository-service is never called.

I fear that the json converter I configured for rabbit and the xml event handling in axon interfere ... or am I on the wrong track? How do I separate command and query service via rabbit correctly, and what is the eventProcessor name good for? I used the bean name of the spring bean handling the eventstream ...

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the two approaches in your configuration are conflicting with eachother. Autoconfiguration uses the absence of specific types of beans to define defaults. However, if you define a bean (even when intended for a different purpose) of an expected type, then that bean is used.

Axon uses Spring's AMQP AutoConfiguration to read messages. If you specify that you want to convert messages in a specific way, then Axon will indirectly use that as well.

A workaround could be to not define the Jackson2JsonMessageConverter as a bean. I doubt the MessageListenerContainer (which Spring uses to invoke the @RabbitListener method) uses the RabbitTemplate, but I'm almost certain it will use any MessageConverter defined in your application context.

Alternatively, you can define the components necessary for reading messages from AMQP explicitly, instead on relying on autoconfiguration. In that case, you could configure an (extra) SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory, and assign that container to your @RabbitListener(containerFactory="") annotation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, allard. I will have a look into it.

Comment: @JanGalinski Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem. What is the configuration for the new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory ? Thx